# Android: Alarm fired up before actual alarm time

Tags: android, timer, android-service, alarmmanager

My app is a tracker app, that uses GPS. At every 15 minutes, it finds current location of user. For this, I had used `AlarmManager`. I am getting The current location through a background service, which is scheduled to run at every `15 minutes`. This service will be started by the broadcast receiver upon alarm. But, the problem is alarm fires up before time, i.e. once service started and finished its work, service was supposed to be called after 15 minutes. But, it is getting called at interval of 2-3 minutes.

**Activity code**

```
AlarmManager AlmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(GpsTrackActivity.this, 0,
                AlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, 15 * 60 * 1000,
                Sender);
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class StartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    private static final String TAG = "StartServiceReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyLocationService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
        Log.v(TAG, "onReceive called");
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service implements
    OnLocationReceivedListener {

private LocationManager manager;
private Location location = null;
PowerManager powerManager;
private WakeLock wakeLock;
private String city, time, udid;
private String country;
GPSLocationListener mGPSLocationListener;
NetworkLocationListener mNetworkLocationListener;
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 250;
private static String TAG = "MyLocationService";
LocTimerTask mTimerTask;
int mSattelites;
Timer myLocTimer;
int i = 0;
boolean isGPS;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand called");
    getCurrentLocation();
    time = getCurrentTime();
    udid = getDeviceId();
    return 1;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate called");
    powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "mywakelock");
    mGPSLocationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
    mNetworkLocationListener = new NetworkLocationListener();
    wakeLock.acquire();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public String getCurrentTime() {
    String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    return currentTime;
}

public String getDeviceId() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) MyLocationService.this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm.getDeviceId();
}

public void getCurrentLocation() {
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    manager.addGpsStatusListener(mGPSStatusListener);
    mTimerTask = new LocTimerTask(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.v(TAG, "GPS ENABLED");
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L,
                50.0f, mGPSLocationListener);
    } else {
        turnGPSOn();
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L,
                50.0f, mGPSLocationListener);
    }

    myLocTimer = new Timer("LocationRunner", true);
    myLocTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 1000);
}

public String getLong(Location loc) {
    String longi = null;
    if (loc != null) {
        longi = Double.toString(loc.getLongitude());
    }
    return longi;
}

public String getLat(Location loc) {
    String lat = null;
    if (loc != null) {
        lat = Double.toString(loc.getLatitude());
    }
    return lat;
}

public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
        location = argLocation;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}


class LocTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    String provider;

    public LocTimerTask(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i++;
            Log.v(TAG, "Timer Task run " + i);
            location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "in timer task run in if location not null");
                isGPS = true;
                onLocationReceived(location);
                myLocTimer.cancel();
                myLocTimer.purge();
                mTimerTask.cancel();
                return;
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "in timer task run in else location null");
                isGPS = false;
                if (location == null && i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "if 1 max attempts done");
                    turnGPSOff();
                    location = manager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.v(TAG,
                                "if 1 max attempts done Location from network not null");
                        Log.v(TAG,
                                "if 1 max attempts done Location from network not null coordinates not null");
                        onLocationReceived(location);
                        myLocTimer.cancel();
                        myLocTimer.purge();
                        mTimerTask.cancel();
                        i = 0;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        i = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(r);
    }
}

private GpsStatus.Listener mGPSStatusListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {

    @Override
    public synchronized void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            Log.v(TAG, "GPS SAtellitestatus");
            GpsStatus status = manager.getGpsStatus(null);
            mSattelites = 0;
            Iterable<GpsSatellite> list = status.getSatellites();
            for (GpsSatellite satellite : list) {
                if (satellite.usedInFix()) {
                    mSattelites++;
                }
            }
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got First Fix",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Event Started",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Event Stopped",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (myLocTimer != null) {
        myLocTimer.cancel();
        myLocTimer.purge();
    }

    if (mTimerTask != null) {
        if (mTimerTask.r != null) {
            mTimerTask.mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimerTask.r);
        }
    }

    if (manager != null) {
        if (mGPSLocationListener != null) {
            manager.removeUpdates(mGPSLocationListener);
        }

        if (mNetworkLocationListener != null) {
            manager.removeUpdates(mNetworkLocationListener);
        }

        if (mGPSStatusListener != null) {
            manager.removeGpsStatusListener(mGPSStatusListener);
        }
    }
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service onDestroy called",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationReceived(Location mLoc) {
    String lat = getLat(mLoc);
    String lon = getLong(mLoc);
    if (NetworkConnection.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
        new SendDataAsynctask(lat, lon, "", time, udid, city, country,
                wakeLock).execute();
        Log.v(TAG, "net available");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network unavailable",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.v(TAG, "net unavailable");
    }
}
}
```

I have a doubt, does `AlarmManager` gets affected by Timer or TimerTask. I am asking this because within my service I had used Timer, since it takes time for GPS to find first fix.

Comment: @ nitish  use this one 
setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), (15*60*1000), Sender)

calendar.getTimeInMillis()-- systemtime in milli seconds

Comment: @ 0 means triggering time is already over so pending intent will fire automatically

@ calendar.getTimeInMillis() means triggering time based on the it will fire